# SharePoint 2013 Configuration Wizard - Should I use it?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, configuration-wizard

Is it true that I should not use SharePoint Configuration Wizard (Launch the Farm Configuration Wizard) ?

I have read old blogs, common SharePoint configuration mistakes and etc... And people are saying that: "You shouldn't use Wizard".

Here is one example blog: http://nikpatel.net/2011/06/23/why-you-shouldnt-use-the-farm-configuration-wizard-to-build-production-sharepoint-2010-farm/

Why is so and this also applies to SharePoint 2013? (Blog was for SharePoint 2010).

If it true, is there a good guide anywhere? How I should configure SharePoint correctly? Can anyone provide any good guide?

Answer (score 3):

In best practice scenario, it is true. Dont use this wizard to configure all the services applications.

You use the Config wizard very 1st time when you configure a farm and on first server to provision the state services(unchecked all other services applications). Once it completed then on all remaining server don't run it.

Once Farm configured then you need to create/Configured your Services application which you need i.e Search, MMS, UPA etc

If you use the Config wizard to configure your Service Application, then you can't control on services account being used, Database Names, Server Selection etc. In order to custom configuration and following the best practice for each services application, you should configure it either using powershell or Central admin.

[Configure services and service applications in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee794878(v=office.15).aspx)